# Proof that integrating f(x) between a and b is the same as integrating f(a+b-x) over the same bounds?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$$

Is anyone able to show me a rigorous proof of this identity. I understand using a substitution of $u=a-x$ gives rise to the RHS in terms of $u$ but don’t know how to show this implies that it’s also true for $x$?

Comment: $x, u$ are just dummy variables. The integral written in terms of $u$ and the integral written in terms of $x$ (or any other variable) represent the same thing. Because writing $u = a-x$ is the same transformation as letting $x \to a-x$, using the latter keeps everything in terms of the same variable.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand your point. Thank you

Comment: The values of a+b-x go from b to a - you just create a symmetric function around (a,b) which all its values are the same for both functions in that range. Draw it to see it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b-x=z\implies dx=-dz$

When $x\to a,\quad z \to b \quad \text{and} \quad x \to b, \quad z \to a$

$\int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx=\int_b^af(z)(-dx)=-\int_b^af(z) dz=\int_a^bf(z)dz=\int_a^bf(x)dx$